# Push values in Mongo Nested Array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s06sQ.jpg)

Let's say that we have many documents like this in the photo

I have the above schema. I want to find the document based on **_id first** and then push an array of values to **providedServices** which belongs to the _id which is inside barbers array

A little help. Can't seem to find this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the related arrays first. For this, you can use `$elemMatch` or write it as `'barbers._id': { $elemMatch: parameter }`.

Here we tried to find the document by filtering its `id` and `barbers id`. You can change the filter as you wish. It can be only filtered on `barbers id`.

`$` [Positional Operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/embedded-arrays/#std-label-first-match-operator) can be used to update value.
Also, see the MongoDB Documentation: [Update Arrays in a Document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/embedded-arrays/#update-arrays-in-a-document)

Need to write your `DocumentName` and your parameters instead of `idValue`, `barbersId`, and `serviceModel`.

```js
const result = await DocumentName.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
   $and: 
     [
       { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(idValue) }, 
       { barbers: { $elemMatch: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(barbersId) }}}
     ]
  },  
  { $push: { 'barbers.$.providedServices': serviceModel } },
  { new: true });
```

At first, we found the related barbers array inside of all documents. Then we pushed the model inside of the `providedServices` array into this barbers array.

Comment: Very straightforward and clear. Thank you Onur!!

Comment: You are welcome Markos.. Good luck