# MongoDB Update Nested Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to represent a grid structure within a MongoDB. I am having trouble updating a nested object. More specifically, the columns array located within the layouts rows row array element. I have created the following models:

layoutModel.js

```
const LayoutSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    rows: {
        type : Array , "default" : []
    },
})
```

rowModel.js

```
const RowSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    columns: {
        type : Array , "default" : []
    },


    user_id: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
    },
    layout_id: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
    }
})
```

columnModel.js

```
const ColumnSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    column: {
        type : Array , "default" : []
    },

    user_id: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
    },
    layout_id: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
    }
})
```

I am able to find the layout associated with the current user, and then add a new row to the layout database object.

server.js

```
// database models
const Layout = require("./database/models/layout.js")
const User = require("./database/models/userModel.js")
const Row = require("./database/models/rowModel.js")
const Column = require("./database/models/columnModel.js")

app.post('/add-row', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ _id: req.body.profile_id })
    .then((user) => {
        const new_row = new Row({columns: [],}) //create new row database object
        new_row.save() //save object

        //find user's layout database object
        Layout.findOne({_id:user.layout_id}).then((layout) => {
          //found user's layout
          layout.rows = [new_row, ...layout.rows] //add new row to array of all the old rows
          layout.save() //save object
        })
    })
  res.send('Add row')
})
```

[image: database example]

However, when I try to add a new column to the row within the layouts rows array it does not update in the database. I am not sure why.

```
app.post('/add-column', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ _id: req.body.profile_id })
  .then((user) => {
    //user is logged in so get the users layout
    Layout.findOne({_id:user.layout_id})
      .then((layout) => {
         //found layout
         for(let row in layout.rows){  
          let row_id = layout.rows[row]._id.toString()  //current row's id
          if(row_id === req.body.var_row_id){           //found row to add column to
           const new_column = new Column({column: [],}) //create new column database object
           new_column.save()
           layout.rows[row].columns = [...layout.rows[row].columns, new_column] //add new column to array of all the old columns
           layout.save()
          }
         }
     })
     
  })
})
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this post can be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74066539/push-values-in-mongo-nested-array/74066773#74066773 . You can find the related row element by using elemMatch first, as done in this post. And then push the new column into the found row. You can apply the same findOneAndUpdate logic for the Layout document