# access mongoose scheme unit and use as an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
      type: String,
      unique: true //< Adds a unique index
   },
  password: String,
  email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true //< Adds a unique index
   },
  categoryLinks: { type:Array, "default": [] },
  links : { type : Array , "default" : [] },
  imagelink: String,
  plan: String,
  bakiye: Number,
});
```

I want to have `categoryLinks` as an array which contains multiple objects of same type yet failing to do this on mongoose.

I tried (to illustrate):

```
categoryLinks: {
    type: {Array, default: [ {"label": String, "link":String, "links": []}, {/*more of the same type..*/} ] }, 
}
```

so when I find a user with `findOne` I can access the `categoryLinks` as

```
 await userModel.findOne({
   username: req.session.username
 }).then(
   (user)=>{
   for(var k = 0; k < user.categoryLinks.length; k++){
     console.log(user.categoryLinks[k].links.label + " is now iterating category");
     for(var i=0; i < user.categoryLinks[k].links.length; i++){
       //update user.categoryLinks[k].links... by using push() or findOneAndUpdate??
     }
     //user.categoryLinks.links.forEach()  or can use for each
   }
   
 });
```

I want to access it as I am accessing a javascript object with object keys like this. I failed with this,

possible then update by finding the index by label and pushing to its array (or maybe removing element)

```
await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(filter, {user.categoryLinks[filter.k].links : user.categoryLinks[filter.k].links.push(newLink)});
```

Would it be how to use it as, if I want to update the array inside the object, I can just use push?

So basically, I have an array which contains objects that also contains arrays. How Can I update it by using a function such as `findOneAndUpdate()` ?? could i just be using `push()` method ?

Comment: Is this the answer to your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74066539/push-values-in-mongo-nested-array/74066773#74066773. You can find the filtered array using `elemMatch` and then update it by using the Positional Operator`$` (`$push`, `$pull`, or equalize its value with new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option for you would be to use [Subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html).

In this approach you define a schema for the objects that will be stored in `categoryLinks`. You get all of the validation benefits of a well defined schema but means that your documents could grow out of hand if you have a large number of objects. By that I mean if your application is high volume and you are dealing with tens of thousands of `categoryLinks` objects per user then you can see how that would make the array very large in terms of storage. MongoDB has a standard 16MB document limit. For most applications that is fine.

Define the `categoryLinkSchema`:

```js
const categoryLinkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  label: String,
  link: String,
  links: { type: Array, default: [] },
});
```

Set `categoryLinkSchema` as the value of the `categoryLinks` type:

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
      type: String,
      unique: true //< Adds a unique index
   },
  password: String,
  email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true //< Adds a unique index
   },
  categoryLinks: [categoryLinkSchema], //< Use the new schema here
  //...
  //...
});
```

Now when you want to add an object to the `categoryLinks` array you can do:

```js
app.post('/user/categories', async (req, res, next) => {
   /* req.body = { 
         label: 'New Label',
         link: 'www.google.com', 
         links: ['Red', 'Green'] 
      };
   */
   try{
      const newCat = { 
         label: req.body.label,
         link: req.body.link,
         links: req.body.links
      }
 
      const user = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate({
            email: "test@123.com"
         },
         {
            $push: {
               categoryLinks: newCat
            }
         }, 
         { new: true }
      );
      return res.status(201).json({
         message: 'Added to categoryLinks.'
      })
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({
         message: 'Error on server'
      })
   }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much... my last question is, is it possible to make it unique depending on, ```label``` for example ? so if a user tries to register multiple ```categoryLinks``` it'd return a unique error ? @jQueeny

Comment: @unbaym that's a very good question. You would need to set up a unique index manually via mongosh or compass. It would probably work for creating new documents i.e. it wouldn't let you save a new user with the same `label` but if you were adding an object to the `categoryLinks` array using `$push` you would need to pass in the `{ new: true, runValidators: true}` option but even then I think it would still let you add an object with the same `label`. You would most likely need  to use referenced docs instead of subdocuments.