# findoneandupdate doesn't update anything

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true //< Adds a unique index
   },
  categoryLinks: { type:Array, "default": [] },
});

const userModel = mongoose.model("userModel", userSchema);

var obj = {"label": "bim-Bebek", "link":"https://bim.bebek", "links": ["12","23"]};

try{
  userModel.findOneAndUpdate({email: "deme1@gmail.com"}, {"$push": {categoryLinks: obj}}, { new: true })
}catch(err){
   console.log(err);
}
```

I  try the code above to update a user's `categoryLinks` yet the findOneandupdate doesn't update anything.. I know for sure deme1@gmail.com exists and there is no log of `err` ... When I refresh I still see the `categoryLinks` as empty array... I tried to push a string instead of object, the behaviour is the same.

Comment: I think this question is related to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77730233/21972629) that I've just answered.